# C# WinRT <-> C# WPF connection with TCP

Tags: c#, windows-8, tcp, windows-runtime

I am trying to connect a WinRT App with a normal C# program. One way communication (RT sending) is fine, but I am having problems implementing the other way.

**WinRT**:

```
var _listener=new StreamSocketListener();
_listener.ConnectionReceived += connectionReceived;
await _listener.BindServiceNameAsync("51896");
```

**Program**:

```
Socket s=new Socket(_client.AddressFamily,SocketType.Stream,ProtocolType.Tcp);
//s.Bind(new IPEndpoint(IPAdress.Any,0));
s.Connect(_client.Address,51896);
```

`_client` is the enpoint from which the WinRT app connects, I've tried with and without binding first. The event of the listener is never fired and the connect operation always times out. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: TCP.IP is two way communication, The socket you receive within your server can also be used to send information back. Or does it disconnect after sending information?

Comment: Are you [connecting to `localhost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh780593.aspx)?

Comment: Jeroen: I tried this but the payload never comes through |  Stephen: Yes, both apps run on the same machine atm.

Comment: @StephenCleary: The app is in the LoopbackExempt and I tried running it on to different machines. In both cases neither connecting with a new socket, nor sending over the exisiting connection works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem. My code for reading data out of the socket was missing one line:

```
public async void read()
{
  using(var dr=new DataReader(_client.InputStream))
  {
    dr.InputStreamOptions=InputStreamOptions.Partial;
    while(true)
    {
      await dr.LoadAsync(1024); //I was missing this line, this is the actual read from the stresm
      byte[] data=new byte[dr.UnconsumedBufferLength];
      dr.ReadBytes(data); //This just interprets the byte read before
      if(data.Length>0)
        CommandReceived.Fire(IComman.FromData(data)); 
      await Task.Delay(15);
    }
  }
}
```